# Flot Chart Line Limits

Tags: flot

I have all sorts of working data-sets that gets displayed correctly in my Flot line charts, however no matter how much data I feed it the chart will not plot more than seven lines.  I cannot find any information that has to do with limits.  It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the legend either because if I turn off the legend nothing changes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: More than seven data sets should be possible. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for example as a code snippet or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can check that.

Comment: Problem solved.  It turns out is was a grouping error in my sql...  oops

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turns out is was a grouping error in my sql... oops